# Creating of folder and subfolder(linked to database userid

Tags: php

Creating of folder and subfolder(linked to database userid.The subfolder is not being created where images of the user will be deployed.Please if anyone can hekp I have been battling with this a while.Here is the code below

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
    $storeFolder = '../../advertiser_images/'.str_replace("#","",$_SESSION["userID"]);   



    if (!empty($_FILES)) 
    {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                 
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
        $targetFile =  $targetPath.$_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    }
    include_once '../../modules/database/db-functions.php'; 

    $data = array();

    $data[0] = 'booklook';
    $data[1] = 'book_images';
    $data[2] = 'vid';
    $data[3] = '#'.$_SESSION["vid"];
    $data[4] = 'did';
    $data[5] = $_SESSION["userID"];
    $data[6] = 'iid';
    $data[7] = $_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $data[8] = 'img_loc';
    $data[9] = 'advertiser_images/'.str_replace("#","",$_SESSION["userID"]).'/'.$_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);

    add($data);


?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: No JavaScript, HTMNL or MySQL in this question so removed those tags.

Answer (score 0):

use this to create your folder by name

```
if(!file_exists('folder name'))
{ 
   mkdir('folder name',755);
}
```

Comment: No but I want the folder to generate automatically when the user is created.A folder should be created within advertiser_images that relates to the usersid and the images uploaded by the user should go in this subfolder